# How to solve confilct between two namespace?

Tags: c#-4.0, resharper

If I have namespace with two classes. I want to use class from one namespace and I have Resharpner tool. Even I select full qualifies name of my Font class it will use Font from System namespace. How to use label and will it removed debugging capability

using System.Windows.Forms;

using Cy.GlobalSettings.ChartSettings;

but have problem

current namespace is Cy.GlobalSettings.ChartSettingsUC;

Font class has a confilct?

Comment: Please add some code to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename classes if the class name is the same in both referenced namespace. If both namespace have a class called Font you can create an alias for a namespace or a type:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Cy.GlobalSettings.ChartSettings;
using CyFont = Cy.GlobalSettings.ChartSettings.Font // This is the full name of the Font class which is causing the conflict. 


Font y; // class from System.Windows.Forms
CyFont x; // class from Cy.GlobalSettings.ChartSettings
```

After this you can use both Font and CyFont in your code without conflicts.

using Directive (C# Reference)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(v=vs.80).aspx

Fully qualified name should work as well.